# change language bibstyle lni

Tags: bibtex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline,oneside,openany,toc=listof,hidelinks]{scrreprt}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem} 
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{bibstyle/lni}


\begin{document}


test \citep{Bruns2015}\\
test2 \citep{White2004}


\bibliography{Quelle}


    \bibliography{Quelle}



\end{document}


@book{Bruns2015,
address = {Wiesbaden},
author = {Bruns, Ralf and Dunkel, J{\"{u}}rgen},
edition = {1},
publisher = {Springer Vieweg Verlag},
title = {{Complex Event Processing Komplexe Analyse von massiven Datenstr{\"{o}}men mit CEP}},
year = {2015}
}
@article{White2004,
author = {White, Stephen A.},
journal = {BPTrends},
pages = {1-11},
title = {{Introduction to BPMN}},
year = {2004}
}
```

[image]

Is it possible to change pp to Seite and edition to Auflage

Comment: You will have to edit the bibliography style file `lni.bst`. From where might one obtain a copy of this file?

Comment: thy mico, works great

Comment: @cfr you are absolutely right. Deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a global batch edit of your pre-compiled `*.bbl` file to get the desired result. Just make sure to do this after including all the citations you want in your document, otherwise you'll have to keep repeating the batch edit after every new compilation.

In your bash shell, run:

```
sed 's/pp./Seite/g' <filename>.bbl > <newfilename>.bbl

sed 's/edition/Auflage/g' <filename>.bbl > <newfilename>.bbl
```

That will replace all occurrences of `pp.` & `edition` in the given `*bbl` file with `Seite` & `Auflage` as needed and the output will be saved in a new file.

Better method would be to replace these tokens within the same `*.bbl` file and save the un-edited version of that same file with a `*.bak` suffix. You can do that as follows:

```
sed -i.bak 's/pp./Seite/g' <filename>.bbl

sed -i.bak 's/edition/Auflage/g' <filename>.bbl
```

Now the only thing remains is to make use of this edited file.

If you are sure, that you won't run the `bibtex` again for another round of compilation, then simply replace `\bibliography{..}` with `\input{<filename>.bbl}` *(Output of second set of* `sed` *commands)*.

However, if you are midway through your document and just want to test if `sed` has done its job properly, then replace `\bibliography{..}` with `\input{<newfilename>.bbl}` *(Output of first set of* `sed` *commands)*. Though, while doing this, if you want to compile your document again, do not forget to switch back to `\bibliography{..}` in place of `\input{<newfilename>.bbl}`.

Hope this helps! Happy hunting!

### **Addendum**

`sed` : is **s**tream **ed**itor, but can edit files directly too.

`s` : is used to replace the found expression *"foo"* with *"bar"*

`-i` is used to edit in place in the given filename `<filename>.*`

`g` : is for *"global"*, means do this for the whole line. If you exclude the `g` flag and *"foo"* appears twice in the same line, only the first occurence of *"foo"* is replaced with *"bar"* and rest remain unchanged as *"foo"*.